# Are there any .NET alternatives to RDDtool?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, cacti

I've never heard about [RDDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/index.en.html) or [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/index.php) until the StackOverflow krew mentioned it in a blog, which is how they keep tabs on their network bandwidth.

Are there any .NET alternatives to RDDtool or Cacti? I will not install MySql and/or PHP on our boxes but would like to leverage the .NET framework & IIS that exists on them. We also have access to a sql 2008 db if required.

So, doesn't anyone know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run RRD tool without SQL it just dumps to local files. We use [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) to graph our network traffic currently - although I'm working on moving it to cacti. You'll need PERL for MRTG though.

We have a dedicated linux box to track this stuff though.

Just out of curiosity why do you refuse to put PHP/MySQL on your servers?

Comment: You don't need to install Cacti on all your servers, just on a single one and you can monitor the others remotely via snmp.

It is a good idea to have a dedicated monitoring server (or a couple for redundancy).

Comment: Ahh that might be why i was confused as to the refusal to put MySQL & PHP on the server - thought he didn't want to put it on the one monitoring server ... Yes there is no reason to put it on all servers, just the one you are using as a monitoring server.

Comment: @Zypher: Every additional piece of software is added attack surface on your server. Its also another thing to remember to manage and update, so I can totally see the point of the question. That said, I'm a big fan of Cacti, MRTG and MySQL. With a dedicated Linux box (as you suggest) at least you can easily setup automatic updates.

Comment: @Zypher - like Luke said, it's more things to setup and maintain. Secondly, we don't have a 'spare' box :: we're paying for a dedicated offsite box (actually, boxes) so there's now way we're going to rent out another one. And i'm not going to put that software on our existing machines. Is it possible to have just an ordinary SNMP windows app show our bandwidth, if I can't use MRTG (cause of perl dependency). ??

Comment: @Luke: Yep I do realize that ... just pure curiosity on my part as to the why ... let me tell you to this day my mom hates hearing the word 'why' come out of my mouth even when it's int a normal sentence.
@Pure.Krome: I don't know of any off the top of my head as we use Linux based monitoring for everything. That being said, i'm sure there is sometihg out there as I said RRD tool just writes to local files and can be used to generate graphs so i'm sure there has to be something out there.